# How to scrape download links inside each folder on S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, web-scraping, data-science

I've been scraping this Dynamic website, which is basically an index link. I want to get all the download links of the files inside each folder down to the last subfolder. I don't know what mechanism should I apply to do that.

**Code:**

```py
    import time
    import lxml
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    
    
    url = 'http://dl.ncsbe.gov.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix='
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    page = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    lists = []
    for tags in soup.find_all('a'):
        links = tags['href']
        lists.append(links)
    
    req = requests.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl.ncsbe.gov?delimiter=/').content #from the network tools in F12
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'lxml')
    names = []
    for common in soup.find_all('prefix')[2:]:
        names.append(common.text)
        names.sort()
    print(names)
```

I just want to get download links for each filetype inside every folder.

Comment: Try this link [here](https://pythonspot.com/extract-links-from-webpage-beautifulsoup/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a public S3 bucket so you can get the `XML` from the root folder:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl.ncsbe.gov/
```

This means you can get that as a response, parse the `XML` and reconstruct the urls for all keys.

Here's how:

```
import requests
import xmltodict

base_url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl.ncsbe.gov"
data = xmltodict.parse(requests.get(base_url).content)

valid_extensions = (
    ".pdf", ".doc", ".docx", ".txt", ".zip", ".xlsx", "xls", ".csv", ".mp4",
)

for item in data["ListBucketResult"]["Contents"]:
    if item["Key"].endswith(valid_extensions):
        s3_url = base_url + "/" if not item["Key"].startswith("/") else base_url
        print(f'{s3_url}{item["Key"].replace(" ", "%20")}')
```

This outputs the entire structure of the S3 in the form of file URLS:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl.ncsbe.gov/Campaign_Finance/2018%20County%20CF%20Procedures%20After%20the%20Election%20New%20Election%20Cycle%20Tasks.pdf
https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl.ncsbe.gov/Campaign_Finance/Audit%20Checklist.doc
https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl.ncsbe.gov/Campaign_Finance/Audit%20Letter%20-%20standard.docx
https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl.ncsbe.gov/Campaign_Finance/ICR-201%20Delinquent%20Repts.pdf
https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl.ncsbe.gov/Campaign_Finance/ICR-202%20Late%20Repts.pdf
https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl.ncsbe.gov/Campaign_Finance/ICR-203%20Noncompliant%20Comms.pdf
https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl.ncsbe.gov/Campaign_Finance/Prohibited%20Receipts-Expenditures.pdf
https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl.ncsbe.gov/Campaign_Finance/e-ICR-201.pdf
https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl.ncsbe.gov/Campaign_Finance/e-ICR-202.pdf
https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl.ncsbe.gov/Campaign_Finance/e-ICR-203.pdf

and many more ...
```